# Create script for table using GO Statement using SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, smo

I am trying to get the create script of table using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo class. I want to get the script having GO statement inside. But SMO omitted all GO statement and the USE from database.

For Example:-
**Create script generated from management studio.**

```
USE [Testing_BlankData_1_Staging]

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[stgUser](
    [UserName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Department] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Role] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Create script using SMO**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[stgUser](
    [UserName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Department] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Role] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want exact copy of management studio. Please suggest..

Please find the code for same

```
public void GenerateScript()
{
    string sqlServer = "My SQL Server instance";
    string sqlLogin = "login";
    string sqlPassword = "password"
    string sqlDatabase = "Testing_BlankData_1_Staging";


    Server server = new Server(sqlServer);

    server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
    server.ConnectionContext.Login = sqlLogin;
    server.ConnectionContext.Password = sqlPassword;
    server.ConnectionContext.Connect();

    foreach (Table table in server.Databases[sqlDatabase].Tables)
    { 

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        ScriptingOptions options = new ScriptingOptions();
        options.ClusteredIndexes = true;
        options.Default = true;
        options.DriAll = true;
        options.Indexes = true;
        options.IncludeHeaders = true;
        options.AnsiPadding = true;

        StringCollection coll = table.Script(options);

        foreach (string str in coll)
        {
            sb.Append(str);
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        try

        {
                string path = "Any path " + table.Name + ".sql";
                System.IO.StreamWriter fs = System.IO.File.CreateText(path);
                fs.Write(sb.ToString());
                fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Execute both statements and you'll see they are actually the same. You don't need to specify the database if it's in your connection string and the `GO`s are implicit

Comment: [`ScriptBatchTerminator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.scriptbatchterminator.aspx)

Comment: Use options.ScriptBatchTerminator = true; but still same result, GO Statement are not in query.

Comment: off topic - I'm certain [Steve Reed](https://www.linkedin.com/in/steve-reed-5721681/) of Google appreciates your use of his picture for your profile.

Comment: Thanks @mjwills the ScriptingOptions.NoCommandTerminator work well

Comment: You may wish to mark the answer to avoid being labelled a freeloader - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348572/encourage-acceptance-of-correct-answers .

Comment: When you output the script to the console, the GO statement is not output. Specify the FileName option explicitly.

Comment: Well done @andy.plsql, this has made it work for me. Thanks.

In fact you don't need to write the file by yourself. You just specify a "FileName" in the scriptoptions and you call whatever Script method. It will create the file :)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest setting [`NoCommandTerminator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.nocommandterminator.aspx) to `false`.

> ScriptingOptions.NoCommandTerminator Property
>
> If True, individual
>   Transact-SQL statements are not delimited in the generated script
>
> If False (default), individual Transact-SQL statements are delimited by
>   using the connection-specific command terminator.

*Also consider setting `ScriptBatchTerminator` to `true`.*

Comment: @vlabatut Feel free to write up a new question.

Comment: I'm just saying the correct answer to the original question has been given in a comment by @andy.plsql . Your answer is not correct that is all.